# You cannot delete this post

Tags: bug

In the review queue I have attempted to flag a few poor answers in Late Answers e.g. https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/130981/8697 *[ <- Now deleted ]* as "This is an “I’m having this problem, too” comment" but informed "You cannot delete this post"

Why?

Comment: I dunno why that would be but the non-answer has been deleted (by me).