# I just got a flagged declined and would like discuss on what grounds so I can learn how to use the flags better

Tags: discussion, flagging

I raised a flag "Not an answer" on a answer to nine year old question.

The question is "[How can I determine the current firmware version number?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/322/how-can-i-determine-the-current-firmware-version-number)"

And the answer I flagged as a "Not an answer" was answering that the Raspberry Pi OS Rasbian has changed name to "Rasberry Pi OS".

In my understanding "Not an answer" should be used "flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer".

And to answer "The OS has changed the name" is not an answer to "How do I check what firmware version I do have".

Please advice.

Comment: This is the same non Answer I attempted to flag for deletion https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2294/8697.  Something has broken on stackexchange, but flagging is at the whim of the moderator

Comment: Im totally confused, my question was linked with @Milliways question, but that question was "Why cant I delete" and mine is "Why was my flag refused"....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies, I declined that flag as I was considering that answer more of an "apple core" or a "rotten apple" as an "orange" at that time, see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/284388). But I now see your point, it is in fact an orange.

I am sorry for the declined flag as there is nothing to remedy that now. Please rest assured that your flagging status is just fine and that your contribution to community moderation is very much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Thx for the answer. I was just unsure and I thought it was better to discuss the issue so I could learn to flag stuff appropriately.